# Vertical Spacing in Tabular with bmatrix

Tags: tables, spacing

I am unable to manually add vertical space between the second and third row.  It should be controlled by the second parameter to `\MyTable` but that parameter seems to be have no effect:

[image]

### Notes:

- The `\MyTable` macro was created specifically for this test case so that I can easily test various settings.  This problem occurs even without a macro being used for the table.
- Using `\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}` just before `\begin{tabular}` does not help in this case as it also stretches out the `bmatrix`.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=21cm]{geometry}% To eliminate warning in MWE
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand*{\MyTable}[2]{%
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}cc@{}}\toprule
    #1 & #2 \\
    \cmidrule{1-2}
    $\begin{bmatrix}
        a_{11} & a_{12} &  a_{13} & a_{14} \\
    \end{bmatrix}$                              & $1 \times 4$ \\[#1]
    % -------------------------------------------
    $\begin{bmatrix}
        a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14} \\
        a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24} \\
        a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{34} \\
        a_{41} & a_{42} & a_{43} & a_{44} \\
    \end{bmatrix}$                              & $4 \times 4$ \\[#2]
    % -------------------------------------------
    $\begin{bmatrix}
        a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
        a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
        a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} \\
        a_{41} & a_{42} & a_{43} \\
    \end{bmatrix}$                              & $4 \times 3$ \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}\noindent
\MyTable{0.0ex}{0.0ex}
\MyTable{2.0ex}{2.0ex}
\MyTable{2.0ex}{4.0ex}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have no problem to see it with e.g. `\MyTable{2.0ex}{12.0ex} ` or `10mm`. The first effect is seen at `5ex`. It depends to the math mode that you cannot really see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know why it doesn't work. But using `\noalign{\vspace{#2}}` works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=21cm]{geometry}% To eliminate warning in MWE
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand*{\MyTable}[2]{%
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}cc@{}}\toprule
    #1 & #2 \\
    \cmidrule{1-2}
    $\begin{bmatrix}
        a_{11} & a_{12} &  a_{13} & a_{14} \\
    \end{bmatrix}$                             & $1 \times 4$ \\[#1]
    % -------------------------------------------
    $\begin{bmatrix}
        a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14} \\
        a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24} \\
        a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{34} \\
        a_{41} & a_{42} & a_{43} & a_{44} \\
    \end{bmatrix}$                             & $4 \times 4$ \\\noalign{\vspace{#2}}
    % -------------------------------------------
    $\begin{bmatrix}
        a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
        a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
        a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} \\
        a_{41} & a_{42} & a_{43} \\
    \end{bmatrix}$                             & $4 \times 3$ \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}\noindent
\MyTable{0.0ex}{0.0ex}
\MyTable{2.0ex}{2.0ex}
\MyTable{2.0ex}{4.0ex}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The spacing inserted with ``\\[<length>]`` is just added to the *minimum depth* of the row; if the natural depth exceeds the minimum depth resulting from this, no space is added. With `\noalign{\vspace{<lenght>}` you're adding the space no matter what. Another way is to say ``\\ \\[-1ex]``, that is, adding a dummy row and some backing up.

Comment: @egreg thanks. I doubted it but was not sure. Thank you.

Comment: This is a good solution to the problem as I don't need to think about how much to adjust the baseline by -- all I really care about is the space between the bottom of one row and the top of the next one.

Comment: Side note, because tabular vertical rules `|` are constructed with individual vertical rules on each row, adding glues between rows with this method will break the rules.

Answer (score 2):

The amounts of extra vertical space you're providing  -- `2ex` and `4ex` -- aren't enough to have an effect. To wit, if you chose `10ex` or `15ex`, the effect is readily apparent.

If you're not sure from where to start the calculation of the desired amount of extra vertical spacing: The "baseline" is where the `1\times4`, `4\times4`, and `4\times3` terms show up.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=21cm]{geometry}% To eliminate warning in MWE
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand*{\MyTable}[2]{%
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}cc@{}}\toprule
    #1 & #2 \\
    \cmidrule{1-2}
    $\begin{bmatrix}
        a_{11} & a_{12} &  a_{13} & a_{14} \\
    \end{bmatrix}$                              & $1 \times 4$ \\[#1]
    % -------------------------------------------
    $\begin{bmatrix}
        a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14} \\
        a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24} \\
        a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{34} \\
        a_{41} & a_{42} & a_{43} & a_{44} \\
    \end{bmatrix}$                              & $4 \times 4$ \\[#2]
    % -------------------------------------------
    $\begin{bmatrix}
        a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
        a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
        a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} \\
        a_{41} & a_{42} & a_{43} \\
    \end{bmatrix}$                              & $4 \times 3$ \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}\noindent
\MyTable{0ex}{0ex}
\MyTable{10ex}{10ex}
\MyTable{15ex}{15ex}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I had erroneously assumed that the space added was from the bottom of the row.

Comment: While this does explain what is going on, @HarishKumar's provides an easy to use solution, so accepting that one instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to add `\rule{0pt}{#n}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=21cm]{geometry}% To eliminate warning in MWE
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand*{\MyTable}[2]{%
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}cc@{}}\toprule
    #1 & #2 \\
    \cmidrule{1-2}
    $\begin{bmatrix}
        a_{11} & a_{12} &  a_{13} & a_{14} \\
    \end{bmatrix}$                              & $1 \times 4$ \\ \rule{0pt}{#1}
    % -------------------------------------------
    $\begin{bmatrix}
    a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14} \\
    a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24} \\
    a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{34} \\
    a_{41} & a_{42} & a_{43} & a_{44} \\
\end{bmatrix}$                              & $4 \times 4$ \\ \rule{0pt}{#2}
% -------------------------------------------
$\begin{bmatrix}
    a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
    a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
    a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} \\
    a_{41} & a_{42} & a_{43} \\
\end{bmatrix}$                              & $4 \times 3$ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}\noindent
\MyTable{6ex}{6ex}
\MyTable{7ex}{7ex}
\MyTable{8ex}{8ex}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This does not seem to work with smaller amounts but only with larger amounts, just as the MWE does.